# Create a nested array from flat array using children (elements) in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Is it possible to convert the array of elements:

```
Array
(
[@attributes] => Array
    (
        [targetNamespace] => http://example.com
    )

[element] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => title
                        [type] => string
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => author
                        [type] => string
                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => book
                    )

                [complexType] => Array
                    (
                        [sequence] => Array
                            (
                                [element] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [@attributes] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [ref] => namespace:title
                                                    )

                                            )

                                        [1] => Array
                                            (
                                                [@attributes] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [ref] => namespace:author
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )

)
```

we can start from "element" key in this case

into nested array based on name of children element:

```
Array
(
[book] => Array
    (
        [element] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [ref] => namespace:title
                                [name] => title
                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [ref] => namespace:author
                                [name] => author
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

)
```

This is the representation of xsd file, and I'm trying to find the rootElement in the schema

Comment: SO do you already have access to the XSD file? What do you mean by root element?  Perhaps one simply element is used in multiple complex elements. In such a case, how would you define "root"?

Comment: Can you tell us the desired output?

Comment: Yes, I have access to XSD file, and this is the only thing I have. It's simple to define root: first 2 elements (title, author) are described in schema, and "book" element contains references to these elements, so "book" is my root. Properly constructed schema should provide such information.

Comment: Desired outout is listed below the "into nested array based on name of children element:". It can be any possible output as long as the "book" element is the "top" key in the array.